# What happens to DOM element when not inserted?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using a code to download an excel sheet generated from HTML content.
The lines that do the download are:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = tipoArquivo + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(formatoExcel);
a.download = nomeArquivo;
a.click();
```

I was wondering what happens to this `a` element when not inserted into DOM tree, if it's necessary to destroy him inserting and removing or if it is destroyed automatically when not inserted.

Comment: I'd say it is eventually garbage collected when nothing points to it, as any other JS variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `a` variable goes out of scope, the object isn't referenced by anything anymore and will be garbage-collected in due course. There's nothing you have to do to make that happen.

If `a` isn't going to go out of scope in a timely manner (maybe something else closes over it), you can clear it to release the reference when you're done:

```
a = null;
```

That's only necessary, though, if `a` will stick around longer than you want the element to stick around.

Comment: When do this GC action will happen? In a large applications there might be some cached data stored in the variables which may or may not be used in the page depending on the requirement. So what happens in that case?

Comment: @Bharadwaj: *"When do this GC action will happen?"* That's entirely up to the browser's DOM and JavaScript engines, both of which are involved. Once all references to the object are released, it's entirely up to the implementation when (or indeed *whether*) GC occurs. *"In a large applications there might be some cached data stored in the variables... So what happens in that case?"* If it's referenced by a variable and that variable is in-scope, by definition the object isn't eligible for GC.

Answer (score 3):

It will be automatically destroyed, when it is not referenced from the code.

Here is article about [Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) in javascript

Answer (score 1):

It'll be kept in memory until garbage collection mechanism kicks in

Answer (score 1):

`document.createElement` method creates a JS object ([element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)) which can be inserted into the DOM tree.

Like any other object created in JS, the lifetime of the element object will be decided by the references pointing to it. If the element is not inserted into the DOM (thus not referenced by the DOM mechanism), it will soon be destroyed by the JS garbage collection process.

Please see [memory management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) for more details.

Comment: *"...creates a JS object..."* Technically, it's a DOM object which is exposed to JavaScript (the JS spec calls these "host-provided objects"). They can be (and historically have been) different from true JS objects. Thankfully those differences have been minimized in modern browsers, but it's still there.